# SplitR function does not recognise dates

Tags: r, date

I was planning to use the SplitR package but I am having problems with the function "hysplit_trajectory". When I try to run the example provided in the documentation, which is:

```
trajectory <-
  hysplit_trajectory(
    lat = 50.108,
    lon = -122.942,
    height = 100,
    duration = 48,
    days = seq(
      lubridate::ymd("2012-02-22"),
      lubridate::ymd("2012-02-27"),
      by = "1 day"
    ),
    daily_hours = c(0, 6, 12, 18)
  )
```

It returns the warning message "All formats failed to parse. No formats found" 24 times, and the generated data frame has NA in the columns corresponding to dates and times.

Trying other dates, it looks like the warning appears for any date with a month or day lower than 10, regardless of whether I write them with or without a 0 in front of the number. That is, dates like "2012-10-12" seem to work normally since they do not give the warning message, but dates like "2012-02-12" or "2012-2-12" show the error.

I am working on Win10, R 3.6.2, SplitR version is 0.4.0.9000. I also use RStudio but the same thing happens without using it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your warning on my R 3.6.2 (on a Win10 PC). I get `trying URL 'ftp://arlftp.arlhq.noaa.gov/archives/reanalysis/RP201202.gbl'
downloaded 109.8 MB
trying URL 'ftp://arlftp.arlhq.noaa.gov/archives/reanalysis/RP201203.gbl'
downloaded 117.4 MB`

Comment: I also get this but after it finishes downloading it says `There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them)` and when typing `warnings()` is when the "failed to parse" messages are shown. I am also using Win10 and R 3.6.2, as well as RStudio (but the warning also appears without using RStudio)

Comment: Please, share the output of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2 tools_3.6.2`